# Laptop fan not turning on when needed

Tags: hardware, kernel, fan

It looks like my fan in my laptop is not turning on when appropriate. I already removed granola (maybe it disables it far too long?)

When I put the computer in sleep mode and resume it immediately turns on the fan (the cpu was waaaaay overheated). So the question is: why does it not turn on when needed.

There are multiple issues here: Why, and how to diagnose this issue? How can I control when the fan should turn on, how do I test that the code is turning on my fan, how do I turn on the fan manually through a command if all hell breaks lose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears it may have been granola. After removing it it seems the fan does turn on, as I hear it working at low speeds at the moment.

Will experiment more, though I can still use help finding out how to diagnose the problem anyways just incase it was not granola and instead a random issue.

Comment: Have not had problems since the removal of Granola. Will contact them to try to resolve this, or diagnose it.